# How to create charts in OpenFrameworks

Tags: openframeworks

I need to create a pie chart in openFrameworks.

Is there an add-on that can help or something built in to ofx that can already do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search it on Github. Some developers write addons without ofx prefix so they are not listed on [ofxAddons](http://www.ofxaddons.com/categories) website. If you can't find what you're looking for, you can try making searches on gist. Many developers upload code snippets that could be used as a starting point of what you are looking for. 
E.g [How to create a pie chart](https://gist.github.com/rc1/3715e673ef175b5e0c93)